# Print text before plotting an image (matplotlib/imageio)

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm pretty new to Python (and really new to using MatPlotLib and imageio), and I was wondering if there was a possibility to first plot an image and **then** print some text.
What I mean: when you give:

```py
print('Test')
plt.imshow(imageio.imread(<location>))
```

It first prints the text and then the image, but when you give:

```
plt.imshow(imageio.imread(<location>))
print('Test')
```

It still prints the text first.
Is there a solution to this? And if not, is there an alternative way to do this?

Comment: Good question, facing a similar problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use `plt.show()` after `imshow`

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt 
from numpy import random

Z = random.random((20,20))   # Test data 

plt.imshow(Z, cmap=plt.get_cmap("Spectral"), interpolation='nearest') # Test plot

plt.show()
print("test")
```

The result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use `plt.show()` after `plt.imshow()`

```
C=np.random.rand(500).reshape((20,25))
S=np.random.rand(500).reshape((20,25))

def function(s,c):
    return s*2+c

dc = function(S,C)
```

---

```
import imageio
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
print('Test')
plt.imshow(dc)
# it first prints the text and then the image, but when you give
# plt.imshow(imageio.imread(<location>))
plt.show()
print('Test')
```

---

[image]